# JHipster Translation issue on Production

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

[image]I have deployed jhipster app on AWS . When I run it from production some of the fields are saying : translation-not-found[myApp.mymodel] But they just run fine on the development server . Can someone help me to  debug the issue as I donot know much about Angular js . Thanks .

Comment: Check in browser console if you can see responses to i18n json files or errors.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou . yes you are right , there is an error . Please have a look .  I have attached the image

Comment: It doesn't seems to be relating with the issue that I have :/

Comment: Can it be that you are running different profiles prod and dev? It can be that you have not build your frontend  for the prod profile and this is the reason why the files are not found. What are you using: Angular or AngularJs?

Comment: @duderoot I am using angular . I do built my front end for prodcution profile as well . This is just an issue for 2 or 3 fields .

Comment: Is this a microservice app or a monolith?

Comment: @duderoot monolith

Comment: try looking here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164936/jhipster-translation-not-founderror-url-not-found/71164937#71164937

Answer (score 0):

As an example I misspelled an entry in the i18n/en/label.json of the sample app. When I navigate to the label page the translation is failing.[image] Then you open webtools and navigate to the *Network* panel and then you can filter only the json resources. In order to debug my missing label title I search in the label.json file for the `jhipsterSampleApplicationApp.label.home.title` but as you can see there is a`jhipsterSampleApplicationApp.label.home.title-1` entry.[image] I you are using internalisation, then you will need to be sure that you are searching for the correct resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @duderoot . I ran it on some other browser and it was working . So , turned out that after clearing cookies on my browser , it worked.