# jhipster translation-not-found[error.url.not.found]

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I am currently working on a jhipster project.
I had to encounter some difficulties with jhipster translation-not-found[error.url.not.found],

that I was able to solve and I would like to share the result of my research.
here is my problem in a few pictures.

[image]

After refreshing the page, the credentials no longer work

**Infos** :
jhipsterVersion: 6.10.5
applicationType: monolith
clientFramework: angularX

###### **Environment and Tools**

java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)
git version 2.15.0
node: v12.16.1
npm: 6.13.4
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Answer (score 1):

Resolution,
The problem is due to the high size of the headers at the FRONT (Angular) and BACKEND (Spring-boot) level.

**1- FRONT correction :**
Edit package.json (Edit the package.json file and add the following parameter On title **webpack-dev-server** and **webpack** : `--max-http-header-size=102400000`)

[image]

**2- BACKEND correction :**
Edit application.propertie files (application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml), add : **server.max-http-header-size: 102400000**

[image]

I humbly hope this helps you
Translator: Google translate

Comment: Have you found which header was huge and why?